# Выделить уровни абстракции в коде, который парсит XML

Tags: java, xml, dom, xmlparser

Есть такой XML файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<groups>
   <group name="ГР1">
   <students>
     <student>
        <surname>Аверьянов</surname>
        <name>Игорь</name>
        <middleName>Анатольевич</middleName>
        <rating>100</rating>
     </student>
     <student head="true">
        <surname>Агафонова</surname>
        <name>Татьяна</name>
        <middleName>Витальевна</middleName>
        <rating>69</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Адук</surname>
        <name>Игорь</name>
        <middleName>Борисович</middleName>
        <rating>75</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Аксенов</surname>
        <name>Алексей</name>
        <middleName>Геннадьевич</middleName>
        <rating>80</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Аксенов</surname>
        <name>Дмитрий</name>
        <middleName>Викторович</middleName>
        <rating>58</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Бабкин</surname>
        <name>Сергей</name>
        <middleName>Николаевич</middleName>
        <rating>65</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Байдин</surname>
        <name>Александр</name>
        <middleName>Иванович</middleName>
        <rating>76</rating>
     </student>
   </students>
   </group>
   <group name="ГР2">
  <students>
     <student>
        <surname>Базаров</surname>
        <name>Андрей</name>
        <middleName>Викторович</middleName>
        <rating>71</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Балихина</surname>
        <name>Ольга</name>
        <middleName>Вячеславовна</middleName>
        <rating>82</rating>
     </student>
     <student head="true">
        <surname>Башмакова</surname>
        <name>Елена</name>
        <middleName>Сергеевнa</middleName>
        <rating>85</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Вдовин</surname>
        <name>Виталий</name>
        <middleName>Юрьевич</middleName>
        <rating>58</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Вдовин</surname>
        <name>Евгений</name>
        <middleName>Федорович</middleName>
        <rating>75</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Григорьев</surname>
        <name>Павел</name>
        <middleName>Владимирович</middleName>
        <rating>70</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Данилов</surname>
        <name>Николай</name>
        <middleName>Валентинович</middleName>
        <rating>83</rating>
     </student>
  </students>
  <head />
   </group>
   <group name="ГР3">
  <students>
     <student>
        <surname>Васильев</surname>
        <name>Максим</name>
        <middleName>Викторович</middleName>
        <rating>54</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Величко</surname>
        <name>Ольга</name>
        <middleName>Валерьевна</middleName>
        <rating>79</rating>
     </student>
     <student head="true">
        <surname>Гаврилов</surname>
        <name>Роман</name>
        <middleName>Николаевич</middleName>
        <rating>60</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Долгов</surname>
        <name>Николай</name>
        <middleName>Алексеевич</middleName>
        <rating>95</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Дюков</surname>
        <name>Владимир</name>
        <middleName>Евгеньевич</middleName>
        <rating>97</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Емельянов</surname>
        <name>Дмитрий</name>
        <middleName>Юрьевич</middleName>
        <rating>75</rating>
     </student>
     <student>
        <surname>Ерохин</surname>
        <name>Александр</name>
        <middleName>Викторович</middleName>
        <rating>89</rating>
     </student>
  </students>
  <head />
```

Я его порсю с помощью JDOM
создал два класса: Students и Groups

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Groups {
    private String group;
    private List<Students> listStudents;

    public String getGroup(){
        return this.group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group){
        this.group = group;
    }

    public List<Students> getListStudents(){
        return this.listStudents;
    }

    public void setListStudents(Students listStudents){
        this.listStudents.add(listStudents);
    }

    public String toString(List<Students> listStudents){
        String strResult = this.getGroup();
        System.out.println("group: " + this.getGroup());
        for(int i = 0; i < listStudents.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(listStudents.get(i).getFirst_name());
            strResult += listStudents.get(i).getFirst_name();
        }
        return strResult;
    }
}

public class Students {
    private String last_name;
    private String first_name;
    private String patronymic;
    private int rating;
    private boolean role;

    public String getLast_name(){
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name){
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getFirst_name(){
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name){
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getPatronymic(){
        return patronymic;
    }

    public void setPatronymic(String patronymic){
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
    }

    public int getRating(){
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating){
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public boolean getRole(){
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(boolean role){
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "last_name=" + getLast_name() + "::first_name=" +         getFirst_name() + "::patronymic=" +
            getPatronymic() + "::rating=" + getRating() + "::role=" + getRole();
}
```

[image: иерархия групп]

теперь самое главное- распарсить этот XML. То, что касается заполенения списка объектов Students- вроде, все хорошо, а вот обернуть это дело в Groups у меня не получается, явно в чем-то логика нарушена, а где я не пойму.

```
public class DomXmlReader {
List<Groups> listGroups = new ArrayList<>();

public void readXML(String filepath) {
    File xmlFile = new File(filepath);
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;


    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(xmlFile);

        Element element = document.getDocumentElement();

        NodeList grList = element.getElementsByTagName("group");
       // groups.setGroup(element.getAttribute("name"));
        for(int i = 0; i < grList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node t = grList.item(i);
            Element el = (Element) t;
            String p = el.getAttribute("name");
            //listGroups.add(getGroupsName(p));
        }
        NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName("student");

        List<Students> listStudents = new ArrayList<>();
       // List<Groups> listGroups = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++ ) {
                listStudents.add(getStudents(nodeList.item(i)));
              //  listGroups.add(setGroupsSt(listStudents.get(i)));
        }

       // for(Groups gr : listGroups)
         //   System.out.println(gr.toString(listStudents));
        for(Students student : listStudents)
            System.out.println(student.toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Students getStudents(Node node) {
    Students stud = new Students();
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element element = (Element) node;
       // stud.setRole(Boolean.valueOf(getTagValue("role", element)));
        stud.setFirst_name(getTagValue("surname", element));
        stud.setPatronymic(getTagValue("name", element));
        stud.setLast_name(getTagValue("middleName", element));
        stud.setRating(Integer.parseInt(getTagValue("rating", element)));
    }

    return stud;
}

private Groups getGroupsName(String name){
    Groups group = new Groups();
    group.setGroup(name);

    return group;
}

private Groups setGroupsSt(Students student){
    Groups group = new Groups();
    group.setListStudents(student);

    return group;
}

private String getTagValue(String tag, Element element){
    NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
    Node node = (Node) nodeList.item(0);

    return node.getNodeValue();
}
```

}

Comment: А что не так то работает расскажите

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось из XML передать данные в объекты класса Students, а Students нужно добавить в объекты класса Groups и еще нужно вытащить атрибут "номер группы" и также передать в объект класса Groups. т.е. сделать иерархию как на картинке [image: введите сюда описание изображения]